# How to run and deploy Xcode 4.2 project in Xcode 3.2 and iOS 4.2 device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, xcode3.2

Currently i am working on Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5 sdk. I have created the project with core data framework. I have designed the screens and deployed in iOS 5 devices.

I want to run my project in Xcode 3.2 because i want to deploy the app in iOS 4.2 devices.

So when i tried to run that project in Xcode 3.2 with iOS 4.2 sdk simulator, there is no errors in Project settings but i have got errors in AppDelegate and main.m file.  because i know Appdelegate and main.m file could be changed in Xcode 4.2. Thats why its not supported in Xcode 3.2.

I have cleared that errors that means i have changed that file as like support in Xcode 3.2. but when i running project i have seen only flash screen only and there is no others output(just blank screen).

How to solve these problems and how to run my project in Xcode 3.2 with iOS 4.2 sdk?

Please help in this regards!!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: did you use storyboard in xcode 4.2?

Comment: No.. i didn't use storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating app in Xcode 4.2 with ios 5, it can not be run in old ixcode because new ios contain two new property like "Strong and "weak" which not available in old ios. I face the same problem earlier and didn't find out solution. Change the code of main like your old project main. I am not sure it work

Xcode 3.2

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

Xcode 4.2

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```